# get_usermeta works where get_user_meta doesn't

Tags: php, wordpress

Why would this simple code produce the following the result? The standard get_user_meta is not able to retrieve a value for the meta key.

```
$billing_user = get_billing_user();
echo('usermeta: '.get_usermeta($billing_user,'GHC_church_city'));
echo('<br>');
echo('user_meta: '.get_user_meta($billing_user,'GHC_church_city',true));
```

---

usermeta: Sydney
user_meta:

Comment: curious what is the value and type of `$billing_user`?

Comment: It’s the user id. Not the user object

Comment: what i the `type`?  Have you confirmed its an `int`?

Answer (score -1):

only guessing but.....

do you have any polyfills in there? plugins like MPMU?

get_usermeta casts (int) against the arg user_id, is get_billing_user returning an object in which case it's maybe not properly getting the user_id?